# Magento - Widget Development

Tags: php, magento

i'm trying to develop a widget for magento cms and I'm having some problems.

I'm very new to Magento so please take it easy on me.

So, the widget consists of an image, some text and a hyperlink.

1. I created a file, MP_All.xml, in /app/etc/modules/
2. Created the widget folder structure in /app/code/local/MP - MP folder was created for the widget.
3. Inside MP folder is a BP_Widget folder containing the Block, Helper, Model and etc directories.
4. in the /etc directory is a config.xml and widget.xml
5. in the Block is a Banners.php file and in the Helper directory is a data.php file.
6. in the Model directory is a Options.php file.

Here's the code of the created files.

/app/etc/modules/MP_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MP_BP_Widget>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MP_BP_Widget>
  </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/MP/BP_Widget/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MP_BP_Widget>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MP_BP_Widget>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
        <bp_widget>
            <class>MP_BP_Widget_Block</class>
        </bp_widget>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <bp_widget>
            <class>MP_BP_Widget_Helper</class>
        </bp_widget>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <bp_widget>
            <class>MP_BP_Widget_Model</class>
        </bp_widget>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/MP/etc/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
  <bp_widget_banners type="bp_widget/banners" translate="name description" module="bp_widget">
    <name>Product Banners</name>
    <description>Create product banners with hyperlink to specific page/product/URL</description>
    <parameters>
        <link_options>
            <label>Link</label>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <type>text</type>
        </link_options>
    </parameters>
  </bp_widget_banners>
</widgets>
```

/app/code/local/MP/BP_Widget/Block/Banners.php

```
class MP_BP_Widget_Block_Banners extends Mage_Core_Block_Template implements Mage_Core_Block_Interface {

    protected function _toHtml () {

    }
 }
```

/app/code/local/MP/BP_Widget/Helper/data.php

```
class MP_BP_Widget_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

/app/code/local/MP/BP_Widget/Model/Options.php

```
class MP_BP_Widget_Model_Options {
    public function toOptionArray () {
        return array(
            array( 'value' => 'test_option', 'label' => 'Test Option' ),
            array( 'value' => 'inquiry', 'label' => 'Inquiry' )
        );
    }
}
```

The tutorial i've followed now says that the widget its supposed to be active and "ready to use". But it still doesnt show up in the dropdown with the available widgets. What am I missing here?

Is there any reference about the XML Schema and the rules of widget development for Magento?

I'm very new to Magento as I've said before. Thanks in advance. Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with the name of your module Directory BP_Widget.

In Magento the "_" character in class names is replaced by "/" Directory Separator when the Autoloader try to load the class see:
`lib/Varien/Autoload.php::autoload()`

So you will need to rename your Module Directory to BPWidget and make the following changes

/app/etc/modules/**MP_BPWidget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
      <MP_BPWidget>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
      </MP_BPWidget>
    </modules>
  </config>
```

/app/code/local/MP/**BPWidget**/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
      <MP_BPWidget>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
      </MP_BPWidget>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <blocks>
         <bp_widget>
            <class>MP_BPWidget_Block</class>
         </bp_widget>
       </blocks>
       <helpers>
         <bp_widget>
          <class>MP_BPWidget_Helper</class>
         </bp_widget>
       </helpers>
       <models>
         <bp_widget>
           <class>MP_BPWidget_Model</class>
         </bp_widget>
       </models>
     </global>
  </config>
```

/app/code/local/MP/**BPWidget**/etc/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
  <bp_widget_banners type="bp_widget/banners" translate="name description" module="bp_widget">
     <name>Product Banners</name>
     <description>Create product banners with hyperlink to specific page/product/URL</description>
     <parameters>
        <link_options>
           <label>Link</label>
           <visible>1</visible>
           <type>text</type><!-- select for dropdown type -->
           <!-- In case you need your source model for this option uncomment source_model node -->
           <!--<source_model>bp_widget/options</source_model>-->
        </link_options>
     </parameters>
  </bp_widget_banners>
</widgets>
```

/app/code/local/MP/**BPWidget**/Block/Banners.php

```
class MP_BPWidget_Block_Banners extends Mage_Core_Block_Template implements Mage_Core_Block_Interface {

     protected function _toHtml () {
            // You need to return your widget html as string here
    }
}
```

/app/code/local/MP/**BPWidget**/Helper/**Data.php**

```
class MP_BPWidget_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

/app/code/local/MP/**BPWidget**/Model/Options.php

```
class MP_BPWidget_Model_Options {
    public function toOptionArray () {
        return array(
            array( 'value' => 'test_option', 'label' => 'Test Option' ),
            array( 'value' => 'inquiry', 'label' => 'Inquiry' )
        );
    }
}
```

A good reference could be this link [create custom widget](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-widget-development-in-magento--cms-23015)

Hope it helps :) and welcome to Magento Development